# GoCD build issue

Tags: gitlab, go-cd

Modification check failed for material: URL:...git

Error performing command: --- Command --- git config remote.origin.url --- Environment --- {} --- INPUT ---- --OUTPUT --- --- ERROR --- STDERR: fatal: Could not change back to '/var/lib/go-server/pipelines/flyweight/

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that latest version of GOCD and plugins are installed
- Stop GOCD server and delete all the contents from flyweight folder, and start it again